# How to save bootstrap tab values one by one using mvc 4?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, json.net, asp.net-ajax

Let me explain clearly, I'm having bootstrap tab(tab 1: Country,tab 2: State)
tab 1: contains some fields like datatable,dropdown,checkbox,textbox etc, same thing tab 2 also having that fields.

Question:

when user click save button automatically should save tab 1 and tab 2 values one by one. how to do that on?
-somewhat i have to make loop based on how many tabs. then i have to send to the action method. anyone could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending data in json. or form post